# website redirecting to com.com

Tags: htaccess, url, no-www

Just realized that my website - `http://www.example.com` is being re-directed to `http://example.com.com`. The `http://example.com` version is working fine though. Below is the redirect chain:

```
http://www.example.com
301 Moved Permanently
http://example.com.com/
302 Moved Temporarily
http://example.com.com/r.html
200 OK
```

I have checked *.htaccess* and cPanel redirects and everything else. But cannot figure out why this is happening. Just to be clear, I did not add this redirect.

Any idea on how this can be changed? I already have regex in *.htaccess* to redirect `www` to `no-www`.

Comment: `example.com.com` - As you are no doubt aware - this is a completely different website. This could be a simple miss-config (in .htaccess perhaps) or the result of a malicious attack. You will need to post your .htaccess file to convince us that this is not the cause of the problem, otherwise best guess is a hacked script... somewhere?! Although the fact that `example.com` is "working fine" does perhaps suggest a miss-config.

Comment: @w3dk I wrote each line of .htaccess and can 100% assure you that there is no 301 redirect to that website there. I double checked just now anyway, and it's not there. Is there any other setting that can be changed (in WHM?) so that this redirect happens?

Comment: I know of no other "setting" that would trigger such a redirect. What kind of site are you running, a CMS of some kind, or entirely bespoke? Do you have any other .htaccess files? You state that you "already have regex in .htaccess to redirect www to no-www" - however, the very first redirect in the chain posted is erroneous, which perhaps suggests something at the server level? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: Please post your .htaccess file anyway! You have the best of the best here, @w3dk, and you could have made a simple mistake that is not self evident. Cheers!!

Comment: Some time back I was trying to find solutions to similar issues. See: http://www.askapacheDOTcom/htaccess/htaccess.html

Comment: If you are using cpanel, first thing I would do is a DNS reset.  See what happens.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without knowing what is in your configuration files.